# get results from two OR queries with AND in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am combing two OR queries with AND in mongoose but not getting desired result

```
{
  _id :"23432ferf",
  "catId" : 21,
  "attributes": [
        {
          "_id": "571237bfc02aad440c216f67",
          "attributeValueM": "metal|Frame Material"
        },
        {
          "_id": "571237bfc02aad440c216f66",
          "attributeValueM": "green|color"
        }
  ]
},
{
   _id :"23432ferh",
  "catId" : 21,
  "attributes": [
        {
          "_id": "571237bfc02aad440c216f67",
          "attributeValueM": "metal|Frame Material"
        },
        {
          "_id": "571237bfc02aad440c216f66",
          "attributeValueM": "blue|color"
        }
  ]
}
```

now by mongoose query is

```
var condition =  [
           { $or: [{ 'attributes.attributeValueM' : 'wood|Frame Material' }, { 'attributes.attributeValueM' : 'metal/Frame Material' }] },
           { $or: [{ 'attributes.attributeValueM' : 'blue|color' }, {'attributes.attributeValueM' : 'green|color'}] }
     ];

Test.find("catID":21).and(condition).exec(function (err, results) {
          ... // not getting any document
      });
```

how i can combine two OR conditions with AND condotion ?
 **already indexing on attributes.attributeValueM and it is working with simple AND condition given below**

```
[ { 'attributes.attributeValueM': 'green|color' },
  { 'attributes.attributeValueM': 'metal|Frame Material' } ]
```

please suggest

Comment: are you want like this (A && ( (B || C) && (D || E) ) )?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect as a result. Do you want both documents supplied here to match the query? It would be clearer if you demonstrated documents that you both expect to match the conditions and those you don't, since clearly the way you came up with writing the query does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `Test.find("catID":21).and(condition)` you can use like

```
Test.find({
    $and: [
        { catID:21 },
        { $or: [{ "attributes.attributeValueM" : 'wood|Frame Material' }, { "attributes.attributeValueM" : 'metal/Frame Material' }] },
        { $or: [{ "attributes.attributeValueM" : 'blue|color' }, {"attributes.attributeValueM" : 'green|color'}] }
    ]
}).exec(function (err, results) {
     // rest of code
});
```

Comment: if my or conditions in and query are dynamic then how i can achieve same result

Answer (score 2):

I too had trouble with the mix of **AND** and **OR** operations. Here is a simpler example that I worked on. This code snippet did not give me the desired outcome, in other words, the right combination of **AND** and **OR** operations.

```
 awTextsDocuments = await AWTextModel
        .find({
          $and: [
            { name: { $regex: reqObj.q, $options: 'i' } },
            { $or: [ recordOwner: req.user._id,  'company-wide-visibility': { $in: 
                     true } ] },

          ],
        })
        .skip(reqObj.offset)
        .limit(reqObj.limit)
        .sort([mongoSortQuery]);
```

But a slight change gave me the desirable outcome:

```
 awTextsDocuments = await AWTextModel
        .find({
          $and: [
            { name: { $regex: reqObj.q, $options: 'i' } },
            { $or: [{ recordOwner: req.user._id }, { 'company-wide-visibility': { $in: 
                      true } }] },

          ],
        })
        .skip(reqObj.offset)
        .limit(reqObj.limit)
        .sort([mongoSortQuery]);
```

Notice the brackets before and after **recordOwner** and **'company-wide-visibility'**. This made the difference and gave me the desirable outcome.